# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-dnd-scrollzone'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new on React JS, i am having this issue with  'react-dnd-scrollzone'
https://github.com/azuqua/react-dnd-scrollzone

Comment: huh? nothing much to say for a unelaborate question.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo npm install --save react-dnd-scrollzone
```